# Printing quantity of numbers bigger than 10 in an array

Tags: java

How can I print in the Console the number of array elements bigger than a certain value?

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: You'll want to do comparisons. The most simple method here, to me comes with a `for` loop and an `if` statement.

Comment: Please show what you've done and use this to ask a much more specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, you would be well-served to post at least some code that you have attempted to try to solve the issue on your own. As one of the comments mentioned, you will want to loop over the array using a `for` loop, and within that, check the comparison of the element you're on, against whatever number you want (in this case, it sounds like 10).

Here's an example:

```
int[] integerArray = {7, 13, 20, 5, 9, 32, 100, 6};
int elementsLargerThanTen = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < integerArray.length; i++) {
    if (integerArray[i] > 10) {
        elementsLargerThanTen++;
    }
}

System.out.printf("The number of elements larger than 10 is: %s", elementsLargerThanTen);
```